# Слияние двух таблиц pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Устал бороться с проблемой. Не могу объединить два датафрейма по условию. То одна проблема возникает, то другая.
Что бы наверняка решить проблему,
[выкладываю исходные файлы](https://dropmefiles.com/q9ei2) пароль 123

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header=0)
df1['United Music'].replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
df1['United Music'].replace('', 0, inplace=True)
df1['United Music'] = df1['United Music'].astype(int)
df1['United Music'] = df1['United Music'].astype(str)
df1['United Music'].replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
uni = pd.read_csv('United Music.csv')[['Артикул', 'Наличие', 'ОПТ']]
uni['Наличие'] = uni['Наличие'].astype(int)
uni['ОПТ'] = uni['ОПТ'].astype(int)
result = pd.merge(df1, uni, left_on = 'United Music', right_on = 'Артикул', how = 'left')
result.loc[(result['Наличие'] == '0')|(result['Наличие'].isnull() == True), 'ОПТ'] = pd.NA

result = result.drop(columns=['Артикул', 'Наличие'])
result.rename(columns = {'ОПТ':'Цена United'}, inplace = True)
```

Имеется два датафрейма:

1. df1 - сводная таблица (основная)
2. uni - прайс лист

К df1 необходимо добавить uni так, что бы было сравнение по двум полям: df1['United Music'] и uni['Артикул']. Если артикул из df1['United Music'] есть в таблице в uni['Артикул'] и при этом товар в наличии (в соседнем поле uni['Наличие'] значение не ноль и не пустое), то выводится оптовая стоимость товара. Если же товара нет при одинаковых артикулах, то поле остается пустое.
После этих манипуляций, удаляем лишние поля и должно получиться что то подобное, как на картинке ниже. Это пример от другого поставщика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилась данная работа с 13 поставщиками, но с двумя застрял и не пойму в чем дело. Очень хочется разобраться и понять, что я делал не так и как делать правильно. Третий день сижу с этим вопросом.

**username, i need help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрые люди помогли. Проблема была в затаившемся пробеле в некоторых значениях и лечилась так

```
df1["United Music"] = df1["United Music"].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```